# Strange(?) out - of - bound with Stringuilder on array

Tags: java, arrays, stringbuilder

There last 2 days I am 100% brain dead and cant find where the error is... Can anyone give me a tip >>

```
for(String inputString : word)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(inputString);

    if(inputString.charAt(inputString.length()-1) == ']')
    {
        sb.deleteCharAt(inputString.length());
    }
    else if(inputString.charAt(0) == '[')
    {
       sb.deleteCharAt(0);
    }
    breaker.add(sb.toString());
}
```

It was suppose to be a simple function to remove the [ ] characters from a string but everytime I run it I get

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4
```

But only on the third or fourth pass never the first or second.
Confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sb.deleteCharAt(inputString.length());
```

should be

```
sb.deleteCharAt(inputString.length() - 1);
```

Because you want to remove the last character (you did it correctly in the test!)

Comment: I have a special spot on my forehead for facepalms when such bugs happen :)

Answer (score 0):

You're deleting the last char at the `StringBuilder`'s length, rather than length - 1.

`StringBuilder`, not unlike all `String` and array representations in Java, is 0-indexed.

Use the following idiom instead:

```
sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
```

The reason why the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` is only thrown arbitrarily in your execution is likely because of the condition checking for the `]` character, which may not always hold true (hence the offending code would not execute).

Comment: The strangest thing is that only the fist pass had the ']' character the rest were clean.